# How to make a counted value inside FoldRows() function available outside the function in a CouchDB list?

Tags: erlang, couchdb

I have a CouchDB list written in Erlang as shown in the code below. This list will output the count for each and every row. What I need is to "Send" the count after iterating through all the Rows. (Get the final count only).

How can I get this done ? Tried using an ets but couldn't succeed.

```
    fun(Head, {Req}) ->
      Fun = fun({Row}, Acc) ->
        TheType = proplists:get_value(<<"type">>, element(1,proplists:get_value(<<"value">>,Row))),

        case TheType of
          <<"TYPEONE">> ->
            Count = Acc+1;
          _ ->
            Count = Acc
        end,

        Send(list_to_binary(io_lib:format("Count: ~p~n", [Count]))),
        {ok, Count}
      end,
      FoldRows(Fun, 0),
      ""
    end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function works for me:-

```
   fun(Head, {Req}) ->      
         Fun = fun({Row}, Acc) -> 

                  {Val} = couch_util:get_value(<<"value">>, Row, rest),
                  TheType = proplists:get_value(<<"TheType">>, Val),
                  case TheType of
                  <<"TYPEONE">> ->
                      {ok,Acc+1};
                  _->
                      {ok,Acc}
                  end


              end,  
    {ok, Count} = FoldRows(Fun, 0),  
    Send(list_to_binary(integer_to_list(Count))) 
end.
```

It checks if `TheType` is of <<"TYPEONE">> and if it is then it returns an incremented `Acc`. After all the rows have been processed the final result is `Send`. Since you did not provide any documents I assumed that the docs were of following structure: -

```
{  
  "_id": "1fa48be41889b04936c0bf0b570002a2",   
 "_rev": "1-29eb2f161688277924b6a4a4e7ad7a78",   
 "TheType": "TYPEONE" 
}
```

and the view function for the list was like so:-

```
fun({Doc}) ->
  K = proplists:get_value(<<"TheType">>, Doc, null),
  Emit(K, {Doc})
end.
```

Comment: Thank you very much Akshat. It was the exact solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

as it it written, this code cannot compile. So I am guessing some point and try to answer. But usually in this forum you should take care to ask clear questions, with as less as possible open points:

- Head and Req are unused?
- Send and FoldRows are undefined variables
- Rows has an undefined format ...

Nevertheless I can give you some clues

define a filter function that return 1 if the row match your condition, 0 else:

```
Filter = fun({Row},Type) ->
           case proplists:get_value(<<"type">>, element(1,proplists:get_value(<<"value">>,Row))) of
               Type -> 1;
               _ -> 0
           end
         end,
```

then you need a list of all your Rows, which is missing in your code example, let say RowList is a list containing element of the form {Row}.

Now yous can use the lists library to create a Count function:

```
Count = fun(RowList,Type) -> lists:foldl(fun(X,Acc) -> Filter(X,Type) + Acc end, 0, RowList) end,
```

and use it like this `Count(RowList,<<"TYPEONE">>)`

as shown in the shell:

```
27> E1 = {[{foo,0},{<<"value">>,{[{bar,0},{<<"type">>,<<"TYPEONE">>}],baz}}]}.
{[{foo,0},
  {<<"value">>,{[{bar,0},{<<"type">>,<<"TYPEONE">>}],baz}}]}
28> E2 = {[{foo,0},{<<"value">>,{[{bar,0},{<<"type">>,<<"TYPETWO">>}],baz}}]}.
{[{foo,0},
  {<<"value">>,{[{bar,0},{<<"type">>,<<"TYPETWO">>}],baz}}]}
29> E3 = {[{foo,0},{<<"value">>,{[{bar,0},{<<"notype">>,<<"TYPEONE">>}],baz}}]}.
{[{foo,0},
  {<<"value">>,{[{bar,0},{<<"notype">>,<<"TYPEONE">>}],baz}}]}
30> E4 = {[{foo,0},{<<"value">>,{[{bar,0},{<<"type">>,<<"TYPEONE">>}],baz}}]}.  
{[{foo,0},
  {<<"value">>,{[{bar,0},{<<"type">>,<<"TYPEONE">>}],baz}}]}
31> RowList = [E1,E2,E3,E4].
[{[{foo,0},
   {<<"value">>,{[{bar,0},{<<"type">>,<<"TYPEONE">>}],baz}}]},
 {[{foo,0},
   {<<"value">>,{[{bar,0},{<<"type">>,<<"TYPETWO">>}],baz}}]},
 {[{foo,0},
   {<<"value">>,{[{bar,0},{<<"notype">>,<<"TYPEONE">>}],baz}}]},
 {[{foo,0},
   {<<"value">>,{[{bar,0},{<<"type">>,<<"TYPEONE">>}],baz}}]}]
32> Count(RowList,<<"TYPEONE">>).
2
33> Count(RowList,<<"TYPETWO">>).
1
34>
```

Comment: Pascal, it's true that the code given by me won't run directly in Erlang shell. But as I have mentioned in my question, this is a "list" function in CouchDB. So this will run properly when used as a list in CouchDB. Anyway thanks a lot for your answer. You have given it in a well understandable way..